# Can't use preprocess_input as preprocessing_function in ImageDataGenerator in Keras

Tags: python, keras

When trying to provide preprocess_input imported from a CNN package (e.g. keras.applications.resnet) the model raises an error when trying to fit to the generated data:

> ‘JpegImageFile’ object is not subscriptable

Code:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
```

Keras version: 2.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the issue by downgrading Keras to 2.1.4:

```
pip uninstall keras
pip install keras==2.1.4
```

Or by adding preprocessing as the first step of the model using a Lambda layer:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Lambda(preprocess_input, name='preprocessing', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is exclusively caused by using preprocessing (and you still can use an `ImageDataGenerator` without the preprocessing), you can also create a wrapping generator:

```
def wrapperGenerator(dataGenerator, preprocess):
    while True:
        x, y = next(dataGenerator)
        x = preprocess(x)
        yield(x,y)
```

Comment: I was considering this solution but wasn't certain if it's gonna be properly parallelized by Keras. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Hmm.... then a more complicated one is to implement a custom `keras.utils.Sequence`.